# Send log messages from all celery tasks to a single file

Tags: python, logging, celery, python-logging

I'm wondering how to setup a more specific logging system. All my tasks use

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

as a module-wide logger.

I want celery to log to "celeryd.log" and my tasks to "tasks.log" but I got no idea how to get this working. Using `CELERYD_LOG_FILE` from django-celery I can route all celeryd related log messages to celeryd.log but there is no trace of the log messages created in my tasks.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

*Note: This answer is outdated as of Celery 3.0, where you now use [`get_task_logger()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging) to get your per-task logger set up. Please see [the Logging section of the What's new in Celery 3.0 document](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.0/history/whatsnew-3.0.html#logging-improvements) for details.*

---

Celery has dedicated support for logging, per task. See the [Task documentation on the subject](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.5-archived/userguide/tasks.html#logging):

> You can use the workers logger to add diagnostic output to the worker log:
>
> ```py
> @celery.task()
> def add(x, y):
>     logger = add.get_logger()
>     logger.info("Adding %s + %s" % (x, y))
>     return x + y
> ```
>
> There are several logging levels available, and the workers loglevel setting decides 
>   whether or not they will be written to the log file.
>
> Of course, you can also simply use print as anything written to standard out/-err will be 
>   written to the log file as well.

Under the hood this is all still the standard python logging module. You can set the [`CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER` option](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.5-archived/configuration.html#celeryd-hijack-root-logger) to False to allow your own logging setup to work, otherwise Celery will configure the handling for you.

However, for tasks, the `.get_logger()` call does allow you to set up a separate log file per individual task. Simply pass in a `logfile` argument and it'll route log messages to that separate file:

```
@celery.task()
def add(x, y):
    logger = add.get_logger(logfile='tasks.log')
    logger.info("Adding %s + %s" % (x, y))
    return x + y
```

Last but not least, you can just configure your top-level package in the [python logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) and give it a file handler of it's own. I'd set this up using the `celery.signals.after_setup_task_logger` signal; here I assume all your modules live in a package called `foo.tasks` (as in `foo.tasks.email` and `foo.tasks.scaling`):

```
from celery.signals import after_setup_task_logger
import logging

def foo_tasks_setup_logging(**kw):
    logger = logging.getLogger('foo.tasks')
    if not logger.handlers:
        handler = logging.FileHandler('tasks.log')
        formatter = logging.Formatter(logging.BASIC_FORMAT) # you may want to customize this.
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.propagate = False

after_setup_task_logger.connect(foo_tasks_setup_logging)
```

Now any logger whose name starts with `foo.tasks` will have all it's messages sent to `tasks.log` instead of to the root logger (which doesn't see any of these messages because `.propagate` is False).

Comment: Are the log messages buffered or unbuffered?  I'm wondering whether out-of-order log messages is an indication of tasks executing out of order.

Comment: @EricWalker: `logging` doesn't buffer anything. `FileHandler` uses a regular `open()` call, and the default is to open the file in textmode so writing to that will use line buffering (a flush after every newline, which means every log entry).

Comment: Seems there is a typo in 'CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER' (and not 'CELERY_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER')

Comment: @imbolc: I can't find any references to `CELERY_WORKER_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER`, not sure what you are saying here. There is only `CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER` and the `worker_hijack_root_logger` configuration option name (the latter is the 4.x lowercase version of the former).

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, it's about 4.x, you just have to make it prefixed and upper cased to use in `settings.py`

Comment: @imbolc: this answer is about a much older Celery release, however. Nothing in it applies to Celery 4.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree it's not likely TS was asking about future releases :) But people coming here nowadays are probably working with modern versions.

Comment: @imbolc: yes, and for those versions you'd use `get_task_logger`, as stated at the top.

Answer (score 8):

Just a hint: Celery has its own logging handler:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

Also, Celery logs all output from the task. More details at [Celery docs for Task Logging](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging)

Answer (score 1):

join 
`--concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO`
with the command to run celery worker

eg: `python xxxx.py celery worker --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO`

Better to set loglevel inside each python files too