# Temporary changing python logging handlers

Tags: python, logging, celery

I'm working on an app that uses the standard logging module to do logging. We have a setup where we log to a bunch of files based on levels etc. We also use celery to run some jobs out of the main app (maintenance stuff usually that's time consuming).

The celery task does nothing other than call functions (lets say `spam`) which do the actual work. These functions use the logging module to output status messages. Now, I want to write a decorator that hijacks all the logging calls made by `spam` and puts them into a `StringIO` so that I can put them somewhere.

One of the solutions I had was to insert a handler for the root logger while the function is executing that grabs everything. However, this is messing with global shared objects which might be problematic later.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192265/celery-and-pythons-logging-inside-tasks) but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about the StringIO is, there could be multiple processes running (Celery tasks), hence multiple StringIOs, right?

You can do something like this:

1. In the processes run under Celery, add to the root logger a handler which sends events to a socket (SocketHandler for TCP or DatagramHandler for UDP).
2. Create a socket receiver to receive and handle the events, as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network). This acts like a consolidated StringIO across multiple Celery-run processes.

If you are using multiprocessing, you can also use the approach described [here](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-logging-with-multiprocessing.html). Though that post talks about Python 3.2, the functionality is also available for Python 2.x using [logutils](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/10/logutils-using-recent-logging-features.html).

**Update:** If you want to avoid a separate receiver process, you can log to a database directly, using a handler similar to that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935930/creating-a-logging-handler-to-connect-to-oracle/1014450#1014450). If you want to buffer all the logging till the end of the process, you can use a `MemoryHandler` in conjunction with a database handler to achieve this.

Comment: I see your point but that will add another moving part to my setup and I'm eager to avoid that (a separate receiver) which has to be monitored and kept running. My idea was to use multiple stringIOs (one per celery worker actually since it'll run only one task at a time). Once the task is over, the decorator code will get the output which is logged and drop it into a database or something.

Answer (score 0):

For the StringIO handler, you could add an extra handler for the root logger that would grab everything, but at the same time add a dummy filter (Logger.addFilter) that filters **everything** out (so nothing is actually logged to StringIO).

You could then write a decorator for *spam* that removes the filter (Logger.removeFilter) before the function executes, and adds the dummy filter back after.

Comment: I don't know... I use the logging system in functions other than celery task handlers and don't want to mess with the filters etc. there.

Comment: @Noufal:  I'm not really sure about your setup, but couldn't you add a filter to just this extra handler?  I wouldn't think it would affect any other logging.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your suggestion. Let's call the filter you've added `foo`. Now, ignore celery and think of my app. If I have 20 places in it where I do logging calls. I'd have to manually do a `removeFilter` in each of these places won't I?

Comment: @Noufal: You mentioned a decorator, so I was just thinking you'd decorate *spam* (and any other functions called by the celery task) with a decorator that would add and remove the *foo* filter.  ...if you have 20 places in the *spam* function that made logging calls, you'd only need 1 decorator for the whole function...if you have 20 spam-like functions, then I guess you'd have to decorate each one.

Comment: Exactly. However, there was a point I didn't note which is that the celery workers are separate processes and so the problem of shared global state (i.e. the root logger) doesn't really come in that much. I might be able to get by with my original idea.