# Python w/ Celery and RabbitMQ Does Not Behave Normally

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Django 1.4.3 with Python 2.7, Celery 3.0.1 and django-celery 3.0.17 on Ubuntu 13.04.

I have some tasks setup to run time consuming processes.  If I set them up to queue with celery they do not behave properly.  If I run them without queuing them everything behaves perfectly.  Any thoughts as to why this would be the case?

To provide some motivation to my problem.  I need to clone company contracts.  Each contract has multiple offers associated with it.  Each offer has multiple offer fields.  Each offer field has multiple values.  I need to clone everything.

Here is an example of what I'm doing.

```
def clone_contract(self, contract_id, contract_name):
    old_contract = models.Contract.objects.get(pk=contract_id)
    contract_dict = dict()
    for attr in old_contract._meta.fields:
        contract_dict[attr.name] = getattr(old_contract, attr.name)
    del contract_dict['id']
    contract_dict['name'] = contract_name
    new_contract = contracts_models.Contract(**contract_dict)
    new_contract.save()
    contracts_tasks.clone_offers.delay(new_contract, old_contract)

@task(name='Clone Offers')
def clone_offers(new_contract, old_contract):
    for offer in old_contract.offer_set.all():
        offer_dict = dict()
        for attr in offer._meta.fields:
            offer_dict[attr.name] = getattr(offer, attr.name)
        del offer_dict['id']
        del offer_dict['contract']
        offer_dict['contract_id'] = new_contract.pk
        new_offer = contracts_models.Offer(**offer_dict)
        new_offer.save()
        clone_offer_fields(new_offer, offer)

def clone_offer_fields(new_offer, old_offer):
    offer_fields = models.OfferField.objects.filter(offer=old_offer)
    for offer_field in offer_fields:
        initial = dict()
        for attr in offer_field._meta.fields:
            initial[attr.name] = getattr(offer_field, attr.name)
        initial['offer'] = new_offer
        del initial['id']
        new_offer_field = contracts_models.OfferField(**initial)
        new_offer_field.save()
        model = models.OfferFieldValue
        values = model.objects.filter(**{'field': offer_field})
        clone_model(new_offer_field, model, 'field', values)

def clone_model(new_obj, model, fk_name, values):
    for value in values:
        initial = dict()
        for attr in value._meta.fields:
            initial[attr.name] = getattr(value, attr.name)
        del initial['id']
        initial[fk_name] = new_obj
        new_value = model(**initial)
        new_value.save()
```

From what I've observed the `clone_offers` works but the `clone_offer_fields` does not - again, only if `clone_offers` gets called as `clone_offers.delay()`.  If I run this calling `clone_offers` without `.delay()` (not queuing it) everything works perfectly.

Unfortunately I'm unable to log in queued tasks (nothing seems to be written to the log file) so I can't troubleshoot within the code.

Is there an issue calling functions within a queued task?  I'm pretty sure I've done this before with no problems.  (Edit:  Answered below)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT1:
I decided to test this throwing all the methods together.  I was 99% sure this wouldn't be the problem but thought it'd be better to check to make sure.  No difference if I use a single massive method.

Comment: Without spending too much time on this, my initial guess is that you're getting a non-locking (concurrency) problem when you queue the tasks. What I mean is, when you serially call the tasks the data you grab and change from the database will have propagated by the time you call the next task. However, when you line them up and distribute the tasks you may be overwriting some information that's being pulled from another task before it's been committed. The only reason I'm suggesting this is because you're "cloning" objects, deleting attributes, and saving them back.

Comment: (2/2) See this, it might explain what I'm trying to say better. http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2010-February/006341.html

Comment: @Blake VandeMerwe  I had considered this might be a problem.  Thanks, I'll look into it further.

Comment: @Blake VandeMerwe: It doesn't seem to be an issue with concurrency.  I tried to clone a single item, which creates 1 task.  It still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem involved Celery hijacking the default logging.  I implemented the solution given: [Django Celery Logging Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366312/django-celery-logging-best-practice?answertab=votes#tab-top)