# Python Celery - Worker ignoring loglevel INFO

Tags: python, django, logging, celery, django-celery

I'm using the following command:

> celery worker -l info -A django_app --concurrency=10 --autoreload

But DEBUG logs are still pouring out, same goes for when using `-l warning` and `--logfile`

[image]

---

**Any idea why Celery would ignore the log setting?**

---

Further details:

the logs come from the `Python` library `suds` which outputs to the logger using DEBUG.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Celery Logging Best Practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366312/django-celery-logging-best-practice)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I decide to to adjust loglevel inside `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING['loggers']['celery'] = {
                               'handlers': ['console', <etc>],
                               'level': <LEVEL_YOU_WANT>,
                               'propagate': True,
                              }
```

Also I decide to disable some "not interesting" logs:

```
LOGGING['loggers']['celery.redirected'] = {
                                           'handlers': ['console', <etc>],
                                           'level': <LEVEL_YOU_WANT>,
                                           'propagate': False,
                                          }
for i in ['worker', 'concurrency', 'beat']:
    LOGGING['loggers']['celery.' + i] = {
                               'handlers': [],
                               'level': 'WARNING',
                               'propagate': True,
                              }
for i in ['job', 'consumer', 'mediator', 'control', 'bootsteps']:
    LOGGING['loggers']['celery.worker.' + i] = {
                               'handlers': [],
                               'level': 'WARNING',
                               'propagate': True,
                              }
```

Doing so will let you see only logs from you tasks, and not Celery's "machinery".

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER setting](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#std%3asetting-CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER):

```
celery_instance = Celery('django_app')
celery_instance.add_defaults({
    'CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER': False,
})
```