# celery logging in django

Tags: python, django, celery

I have gone through a lot of questions regarding this on SO, but most of the questions are missing the parameters or implementation methods.
So, I'm not able to debug this.

My simple requirement is I want to log all(django and celery) messages to a single file.
This is my `LOGGING` `dict` in `settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s() ] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logger.log',
            'when': 'midnight',
            'interval': 1
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False
        }
    }
}
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
```

Then I have defined this function:

```
@shared_task
def tester():
    import logging
    logging.info("Log this!!")
```

`tester()` is writing to the log file.

`tester.delay()` is not writing to the log file.

What am I missing in this simple thing?

Comment: Did you try this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366312/django-celery-logging-best-practice)

Comment: @ArpitSolanki, Yes I did try it, it isn't working. I'm sure there is something obvious that I'm missing here.

Comment: your logging config does not contain a handler for celery. Try to include that from the link i posted and see if it is working

Comment: @ArpitSolanki In the link, there isn't any default('') logger, should I also create a single logger('celery')? Secondly, am I logging it the right way in `tester` function?

Comment: from that answer console handler will take care of your django logs and celery handler will log for celery logs. I suppose your logging in task is fine

Comment: @ArpitSolanki No luck.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define your default log level, use the root key in the LOGGING dict:

```
...
'root': {
    'handlers': ['default'],
    'level': 'DEBUG'
},
'loggers': {...}
....
```

In theory, '' as a loggers's key should also work, but I haven't seen it in a while and I know at least in one my projects it didn't work as expected.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details