# Can not use celery delay for saved form: object is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-celery

Using Django `1.8`, I'd like to trigger a delayed celery function after a form is saved in views

```
def new_topic(request, forum_id):
    form = TopicForm()
    uid = request.user.id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tform = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if tform.is_valid():
            topic = tform.save(commit=False)
            topic.title = clean_title(tform.cleaned_data['title'])
            topic.description = clean_desc(tform.cleaned_data['description'])
            topic.save()
            notify_new_topic.delay( uid, topic) #<--problem here
            #rest of the views
```

But I get

```
EncodeError at /add/topic/
<Topic: Topic object> is not JSON serializable
```

I don't get any error if I remove `delay` from the celery task.

The task is:

```
@shared_task
def notify_new_topic(flwd_id, topic):
    title = topic.title
    link = topic.slug

    flwd= cached_user(flwd_id) #User.objects.get(id = flwd_id)
    print 'flwd is', flwd.username
    flwr_ids = FollowUser.objects.filter(followed=flwd).values('follower_id')
    flwrs = User.objects.filter(id__in= flwr_ids).values('id', 'username','email') 

    for f in flwrs:
        print 'flwr username:',  f['username']
        if notify_flwdp_applies(int(f['id'])):
            print 'notify flwdp applies'
            make_alerts_new_topic(flwd_id, f['id'], topic)
            print 'back from make_alerts_new_topic'
```

I'm wondering how can I debug/fix this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Task's argument should be serializable (i.e. string, int, etc.). To fix error you can pass `topic_id` as argument and fetch topic object inside task method:

```
notify_new_topic.delay( uid, topic.id)

@shared_task
def notify_new_topic(flwd_id, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)
    title = topic.title
    link = topic.slug

    flwd= cached_user(flwd_id) #User.objects.get(id = flwd_id)
    print 'flwd is', flwd.username
    flwr_ids = FollowUser.objects.filter(followed=flwd).values('follower_id')
    flwrs = User.objects.filter(id__in= flwr_ids).values('id', 'username','email') 

    for f in flwrs:
        print 'flwr username:',  f['username']
        if notify_flwdp_applies(int(f['id'])):
            print 'notify flwdp applies'
            make_alerts_new_topic(flwd_id, f['id'], topic)
            print 'back from make_alerts_new_topic'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This removes the error, but now notification is not generated. Could it be due to the fact that I call a function `make_alerts_new_topic` inside the delayed function?

Comment: @Babr it's hard to say without access to your code. But I suppose it's more likely the error in your program logic. For example check value of `flwrs` variable. If it's empty notification never sent. Same for `if notify_flwdp_applies(int(f['id']))` condition. Check if it's true or not. And at least make sure that `make_alerts_new_topic` works as expected outside of delayed function.

Comment: Well the problem is that the print statements inside delayed function are not printed out in the terminal. So how can I check them? The functions work just fine without `delay` though.

Comment: @Babr you can enable logging. See details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366312/django-celery-logging-best-practice

Answer (score 6):

Since, the solution is already provided, I will try to explain why we can not pass non-serializable objects to *celery tasks*.

#### Why do we need to pass serializable objects to celery tasks?

With celery, we use a *message broker* (like *Redis* or *RabbitMQ*). Suppose we use *Redis*. When a *celery task* is called, the parameters are passed to *Redis* so that the broker can read them. And for this to happen, the datatype of those parameters ought to be supported by *Redis*.

#### Workaround

Suppose you want to pass a `python dictionary` as a parameter to a *celery task*, add these values to the celery configuration:

```
task_serializer = "json"  
result_serializer = "json"
accept_content = ["json"]
```

or you might want to do

```
celery.conf.update(
    task_serializer="json",
    result_serializer="json",
    accept_content=["json"]
)
```

**For other cases**, replace `json` in above with `pickle`, `xml`, etc.

Typical text-based serialization formats are `csv`, `json`, `xml`, `yaml`, `toml`, etc. Binary-based formats are `protobuf` and `avro`. Python also has several packages like `pickle`, `numpy` and `pandas` that supports serializing custom objects into `byte` format. You can also make your custom serializer.

##### What do these configurations do?

1. instruct celery to serialize the python objects first and then pass them to the *message broker*.
2. deserialize the objects from the *message broker* and then provide them to the *celery worker*.

**References**

- [Tutorials Point: Object-Oriented Python - Object Serialization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/object_oriented_python/object_oriented_python_serialization.htm)
- [Issue on Github: Type Object not JSON serializable](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4708#issuecomment-387434974)
- [towards data science: What, Why and How of (De)Serialization in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-why-and-how-of-de-serialization-in-python-2d4c3b622f6b)

Answer (score 2):

Change to picke enoding

```
app.conf.event_serializer = 'pickle' # this event_serializer is optional. 
app.conf.task_serializer = 'pickle'
app.conf.result_serializer = 'pickle'
app.conf.accept_content = ['application/json', 'application/x-python-serialize']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance as json and then recreate the instance from json no need to do database query again like this:

```
serialized_topic = topic.__dict__
serialized_topic.pop('_state')    
notify_new_topic.delay(uid, serialized_topic)
```

Now inside the task recreate the instance from the serialized topic

```
@shared_task
def notify_new_topic(flwd_id, serialized_topic):
    topic = Topic(**serialized_topic)
    # reset of the code
```