# How to disable celery task result logging?

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have working Celery 3.1 app which logs some sensitive info. Ideally I would to have the same log, but without **result** part.

Currently it looks like:

```
worker_1 | [2019-12-10 13:46:40,052: INFO/MainProcess] Task xxxxx succeeded in 13.19569299298746s: yyyyyyy
```

I would like to have:

```
worker_1 | [2019-12-10 13:46:40,052: INFO/MainProcess] Task xxxxx succeeded in 13.19569299298746s
```

How to do that?

**Edit**:
It seems that this could do the job: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/reference/celery.worker.job.html#celery.worker.job.Request.success_msg but I have no idea how to actually use it.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case it's useful to anyone in near future, I found in Celery 4.4 the `success_msg` in the Request class has [been moved to the application tracer](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/5b86b35c81ea5a1fbfd439861f4fee6813148d16/celery/app/trace.py#L52).

Luckily, it seems this can be easily overridden in your Django app's `celery.py` like so:

```
from celery.app import trace

trace.LOG_SUCCESS = """\
Task %(name)s[%(id)s] succeeded in %(runtime)ss\
"""
```

You can change it to anything you like of course, this just removes the return value portion. [Full context here](https://github.com/SamStudio8/majora/commit/44be27261c115acf9e084cd631d21eb72935e6a3).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the success message being sent, remove the return_value format from there. 
For that you need to override the Request class, as described [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/reference/celery.worker.job.html#celery.worker.job.Request.success_msg).

You can also override the logging config as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366312/django-celery-logging-best-practice).

Answer (score -1):

worker_1 | [2019-12-10 13:46:40,052: INFO/MainProcess] Task xxxxx succeeded in 13.19569299298746s: yyyyyyy

**yyyyyyy** is the result that your function returns, to remove that simply return what you want.
in your case only **return** will work