# How do I know much time taken by task?

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery, task is differed using `task.delay()` function. I would like keep log of every task and time taken to finish.

Is there anyway so that I could how much time taken?

In the celery console log, we can see time taken by a task e.g.

```
[2015-12-09 20:13:33,745: INFO/MainProcess] Task start1.add[51563981-432e-423b-b63f-63c980145c8e] succeeded in 0.010178387004998513s: 5
```

Here `0.010178387004998513s` is time taken to finish a task. Is there any way I can capture this variable so that I can store it somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there may be an answer for your problem:

[Send log messages from all celery tasks to a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192265/send-log-messages-from-all-celery-tasks-to-a-single-file)

again, need to make it clear that the log you see from console is the log of `celery process`, celery itself has no ways to log different tasks' log, you have to log that explicitly in the task code snippet.

thanks